# ReactJs is giving an error while compiling the module react-particle-js in typescript-cra template

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, particles.js

```
TypeScript error in C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Work/self/abdullathanseeh2021/node_modules/tsparticles/dist/Interfaces/Options/IOptions.d.ts(1,13):
'=' expected
import type { IInteractivity } from "./Interactivity/IInteractivity";
```

How can i fix this issue. Is there a possiblity to disable typechecking in particular module.

Comment: Which TypeScript version are you using? `import type` requires at least 3.8